# Dropdown menu problems

Tags: html, css

I got this problem that when I hover on my dropdown menu, the background changes and the color does also. But i can't get it to white..
What to do?

http://hcl.konggulerodhosting.dk/index.html

```
    <nav>
      <div id="topBar" data-toggler="is-active" class=" top-bar row ">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="topBar" class="mobile__close hide-for-large">  </button>
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <div class="top-bar-left">
            <div class="site-logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt=""></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="top-bar-right">
                         <p class="mobile__headline hide-for-large">Menu</p>
                         <ul data-responsive-menu="drilldown large-dropdown" data-back-button="&lt;li class=&quot;js-drilldown-back drilldown-back&quot;&gt;&lt;a&gt;Back&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;" class="menu">
                           <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Forside</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Undersøgelser</a>
                             <ul class="menu">
                               <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                             </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li><a href="#">Tilskud</a></li>
                           <li><a href="article.html">Høreapparat</a></li>
                           <li><a href="personale.html">Information</a></li>
                           <li><a href="about.html">Om os</a></li>
                           <li class="search__toggler">
                             <button type="button" data-toggle="search" id="search-toggler"></button>
                           </li>
                         </ul>
                       </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


.is-dropdown-submenu-item {
     color:white;
  }
```

is not working. So i dont know what to do..

Comment: Found this selector in main.css?v=3: `.top-bar.top-bar .menu.menu > li:active:not(.search__toggler) > a, .top-bar.top-bar .menu.menu > li:focus:not(.search__toggler) > a, .top-bar.top-bar .menu.menu > li:hover:not(.search__toggler) > a`, there you have to remove `color: #4f87b7;`

Comment: No. Because that is hitting all the a tags. I only need to hit the a tags in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this image.**............................................

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please don't link your site as it's bad for archiving purposes.

You need to change the link colour.

```
.is-dropdown-submenu-item a:hover  {
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: And that's not a very constructive reply. That is your issue, inspect your elements.

Comment: This will not change the color on it. Try it.

Comment: I did, then I created an answer. Hence why I created the answer.

Comment: Well. That was what i had in the css before also. It did not change anything dude :)